# Why does Scrapy crawl some other urls before crawling the main url?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

The main url that I wan to crawl is `http://192.168.1.1/adslconfig.htm`, but it first tries to crawl this URL `http://192.168.1.1/robots.txt`, and it fails with a status code of 401, and its referer header is set to None as well, so it just wastes a few seconds for nothing

And that's not the only one, it also tries to crawl the main URL that I want but it fails at first, with a referer header set to None

But in the second try, it succeeds with the status code of 200 and referer header of `http://192.168.1.1/adslconfig.htm`

Is it failing because of the referer header?

How can I prevent these two unsuccessful crawls, and crawl the main URL with the first try?

[image]

```
import scrapy

class ScrapperSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    handle_httpstatus_list = [401]
    name = "scrapper"
    start_urls = ["http://192.168.1.1/adslconfig.htm"]
    auth = "Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4="

    def parse(self, response):
        return scrapy.Request(
            "http://192.168.1.1/adslconfig.htm",
            headers={'Authorization': self.auth, 'Referer': "http://192.168.1.1/adslconfig.htm"},
            callback=self.after_login
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the step that crawls the `robots.txt`, I set the `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False` in the settings.py file, so it ignores reading the `robots.txt`, I don't know if it can cause problems, let me know if it does, and what happens if it doesn't crawl robots.txt at first?

And for the second step which fails, I had to change my `parse` method to `start_requests`:

from this:

```
def parse(self, response):
    return scrapy.Request(
        "http://192.168.1.1/adslconfig.htm",
        headers={'Authorization': self.auth, 'Referer': "http://192.168.1.1/adslconfig.htm"},
        callback=self.after_login
    )
```

to this:

```
def start_requests(self):
    return [scrapy.Request(
        "http://192.168.1.1/adslconfig.htm",
        headers={'Authorization': self.auth, 'Referer': "http://192.168.1.1/adslconfig.htm"},
        callback=self.after_login
    )]
```

Notice the `start_requests` method returns an iterable, so it's wrapped in a `[]`

This way the spider uses this method with the correct headers and applies them in the first crawling, and it now crawls successfully on the first try!

[image]

To read about the `start_requests` method:
https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html